# How to assign value to input which is created on the fly

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to update the value of an input field that is part of DOM that is created on the fly without success. 
Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hidden-institution-form hide">
    <form class="form-horizontal forms" role="form">
       <input type="text" id="code">
    </form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//Create an empty Div and clone the content of .hidden-institution-form in it
var frm = $('<div class="institution-form" id="institution-form"/>').append($(".hidden-institution-form").clone());

//Remove the hide class
$(frm).find(".hidden-institution-form").removeClass("hide");

//Replace .hidden-institution-form with .instutition
$(frm).find(".hidden-institution-form").removeClass("hidden-institution-form").addClass("instutition");

//Locate the input field #code and change it value
$("#institution-form").find("#code").val('some value'); //This does not work
```

Comment: "How to assign value to input which is created on the fly" --- **exactly the same** way you would do it for the element that was the part of the initial response.

Comment: `find("#code")`--- so you have multiple elements with the same `id`?

Comment: Btw, where are you adding your just created element to the DOM? You have created it. Not added to the DOM. Then you cannot find it in the DOM. Well, it's not there.

Comment: The element #code I am looking for is only part of #institution-form element, not .hidden-institution-form #code. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

You're not adding the created element to the DOM.

`frm` element is just created in local scope, whereas `$("#institution-form")` searches elements in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Once you remove the class hidden-institution-form you only add the class "institution" so the following code should work:

UPDATE: Among some spelling errors, the methods in which you were using were off.  Try this:

```
//Create an empty Div and clone the content of .hidden-institution-form in it

var frm = $('<div class="institution-form" id="institution-form"/>').append($(".hidden-institution-form").clone());

//Remove the hide class
$(".hidden-institution-form").removeClass("hide");

//Replace .hidden-institution-form with .instutition
$(".hidden-institution-form").removeClass("hidden-institution-form").addClass("institution");

//Locate the input field #code and change it value
$(".institution").find("#code").val('some value'); //This does not work
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/de7Hv/

Comment: You're not dealing with dynamically added element - if you remove creation of element dynamically - nothing will change in your code behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/de7Hv/1/

Comment: So create the element and then get he I'd of it

Comment: I'm not an OP. Please read your code once again. Then my comment once again :-)

Comment: If you want a simple answer you've got spelling errors in your js

Comment: lol. I AM NOT the person who asked the question :-) Please check my answer to finally get what I mean :-)

Comment: Oh sorry I'm on my phone.  Didn't see you weren't op.  Personally I'd just echo the div and then do stuff to it.

Comment: Yes I see.  I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are not adding the newly created element to the dom. So when you do execute the id selector `#institution-form` it will not be able to find the new element.

The other problem I see is if you create multiple instances of this block, there will be multiple elements with the id `institution-form` which will cause a problem in finding the correct element to set the value.

So in places where you clone or create multiple insteances of an element use calsses insted so

```
<div class="hidden-institution-form hide">
    <form class="form-horizontal forms" role="form">
        <input type="text" class="code"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

then

```
//Create an empty Div and clone the content of .hidden-institution-form in it
var frm = $('<div class="institution-form" />').append($(".hidden-institution-form").clone());

//Remove the hide class
$frm.find(".hidden-institution-form").removeClass("hide");

//Replace .hidden-institution-form with .instutition
$frm.find(".hidden-institution-form").removeClass("hidden-institution-form").addClass("instutition");

//Locate the input field #code and change it value
frm.find(".code").val('some value'); //This does not work
```